# How do I return a subprocess in Flask?

Tags: python, flask, subprocess

This might be a stupid question but I'm pretty new to Python and especially Flask, and I can't figure this out. Basically the second decorator in my script is supposed to return the subprocess to the /results page. The ping test that it runs does print in the terminal, but I actually want that printed to a page.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import subprocess

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route("/results", methods=["POST","GET"])
def results():
    get_url = request.form.get("valid_url")
    if request.method == "POST":
        ping_test = ['ping', '-n', '5', get_url]
        return subprocess.call(ping_test)

if __name__=='__main__':
   app.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

The `call` just calls it on the server, it returns nothing. To get the output use [check_output](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output)

```
@app.route("/results", methods=["POST","GET"])
def results():
    get_url = request.form.get("valid_url")
    if request.method == "POST":
        ping_test = ['ping', '-n', '5', get_url]
        return subprocess.check_output(ping_test)
```